# Overflow scrolling div underneath

Tags: css, html

I'm working with a div sitting above another div. When I scroll the div that sits above the other and reach the bottom, it scrolls the entire body. This is hard to explain so I made a fiddle to demonstrate the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/2Ydr4/

HTML:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="above">
       <!-- Content in here that is longer than the height -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.above {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: red;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
}
```

My question is: how do I prevent the body scrolling when the floating div is scrolled to the bottom or top? I'm sure it's something really obvious that I'm missing. Thanks!

EDIT: I should probably have mentioned that the target device for this was an iPad. I've tried adding `body {overflow: hidden}` conditionally as suggested below, and while this solves the problem on a desktop browser, it still seems to persist on a touch-based browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Desktop**

That's how scrolling works. What you will need to do is remove the body's scroll property temporarily or by the users action.

For example you could disable the body's scroll when the user hovers over the floating div by using...

```
body{overflow:hidden}
```

and then re-enable it when you hover off the floating div by using..

```
body{overflow:auto}
```

**Mobile**

On mobile devices you will need to use touch events. I haven't tried this but in theory this should work.

```
var $body = document.querySelector('.body'),
    $above = document.querySelector('.above');

$above.addEventListener('ontouchstart', onAboveStart, false);
$body.addEventListener('ontouchstart', onBodyStart, false);


function onAboveStart()
{
        $body.addEventListener('ontouchmove', function(e) {e.preventDefault()}, false);
}

function onBodyStart()
{
        $body.removeEventListener('ontouchmove', function(e) {e.preventDefault()});
}
```

Comment: Right - that's what I thought it would be something like. I've implemented this in my application, but doesn't seem to work on a touch device. I should probably have mentioned that was the target in my question, I'll update that now.

Comment: Ahh.. You will need to use the ontouchstart & ontouchmove javascript events to prevent scrolling. For example: `document.addEventListener('ontouchstart', function(e) {e.preventDefault()}, false);
document.addEventListener('ontouchmove', function(e) {e.preventDefault()}, false);`

Comment: Yeah - I've tried something like this and it doesn't really work, it ends up disabling scrolling on the entire page and not just on the body. Trying to look for a solution to disable scrolling on the parent but not the child. Any ideas?

Comment: Just looking back at this and noticed that div.body has no height or overlay css properties. Basically div.body has no scrollable component to control. Is this app your building using only vanilla js and css? It would be much easier to do what your asking with a framework like Sencha Touch or JQuery mobile. They don't rely on the browsers native scrollable component. Instead they give you more flexibility and control with custom scrollable components. If a complete library is not your cup of tea you could use something like iScroll instead.. [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your mobile solution! The App is a combination of Angular JS/Bootstrap/JQuery at the moment. I've been looking at different touch libraries such as http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/. I'll definitely take a look at iScroll, I came across it earlier but kind of wrote it off.

Comment: No problem. I would recommend using Sencha Touch for mobile web apps. It is probably the most mature framework from all the stacks available and once you get past the learning curve it's rapid quality development from then on. All the best mate.

Comment: Worked perfect for me. I have an image preview that you can scroll, and this helped me not scroll the body while scrolling the image.